# Change string value from another function in main in C using pointers

Tags: c, string, function, pointers

I have this code, and I want from a string that is stored in value called `original` such as `home$family$fun`, using the delimiter value such as `$`, assign to another string named `final` the word between the two delimiters.  That means that `final` should contain `family` and print the result from `main`. But the operation must be done in another function using only pointer and pointer arithmetic. Also the prototype of the `getPart` function must not be changed.

My problem is that, I get this result to my variable `final` when I am inside the `getPart` function but when I am returning to `main` the final function have only '\0' as value and not the value I wanted it. I think, the problem is something with the addresses, meaning that if the value which string's address change, then the value of string will be changed. But I am a bit confused...Could someone help me?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE 32

int getPart(char original[], char delimiter[], char final[]) {
    int i, j;
    int counter = 0;
    int counter1 = 0;

    for(i = 0; *(original + i) != '\0'; i++) {
        if(*(original + i) == *delimiter) {
            counter++;
        }
    }

    if(counter > 1) {
        for(i = 0; *(original + i) != '\0'; i++) {
            if(*(original + i) == *delimiter) {
                if(counter1 < 1) {
                    final = (original + i + 1);
                    counter1++;
                }
                else {
                    for(j = 0; *(final + j) != '\0'; j++) {
                        if(strcmp(final + j,original + i) == 0) {
                            *(final + j) = '\0';
                            *(final + j + 1) = '\0';
                            //final + j = '\0';
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return(1);
    }
    else {
        return(0);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char original[SIZE], delimiter[SIZE], final[SIZE];
    char format_str_or[20], format_str_del[20];
    int counter, i;

    for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        *(final + i) = '\0';
    }

    sprintf(format_str_or," %%%ds",SIZE - 1);
    printf("Enter string: ");
    scanf(format_str_or,original);

    sprintf(format_str_del," %%%ds", SIZE - 1);
    printf("Enter delimiter: ");
    scanf(format_str_del,delimiter);

    counter = getPart(original,delimiter,final);
    printf("%d\n",counter);

    if(counter == 1) {
        printf("%s\n",final);
    }
    else if(counter == 0) {
        printf("%s does not appear twice in %s\n",delimiter,original);
    }

    return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems:

1. In your function you reassign the pointer `final` to point somewhere into `original`. Reassignment won't work as the pointer is passed *by value*, and the assignment only changes the local variable.
2. By modifying contents of `final` you also modify the contents of `original`.

Both these issues could be solved by *copying* to `final` instead of reassigning where it points.

Both these issues should also be easily detectable using [standard debugging practices](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).